# How override formmaker module controler in prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, module, overriding, prestashop

I have a module and I world like override his controller.
The name of this module is Formmaker and the controller name is form.php
This file is located in module/formmaker/controller/front

I have tried to override this file by putting it in the prestashop override folder and delete the class_index.php file. No work.

Can you help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to inform you about that isn't possible to override modules controller(s) (at the moment).

The solution should be to duplicate the module and edit the controller that you want, so when the module is upgraded you can check the changes with your clone and integrate them.

Or, edit directly the controller, and backup the edited file before upgrade.

The choice is yours.

Have good programming ;)